# How to set a numeric value in the source_mappings.json file in a AWS SDLF pipeline?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, pipeline, aws-glue, data-lake

There is a framework used to ingest files into a DataLake in AWS S3, the name is Serverless DataLake Framework aka SDLF, some configuration is needed to move a file through many stages in the S3 repository.
The first one is to pass a file from the S3/Landing stage to S3/Raw stage.
To do that part of the configuration is the file: source_mappings.json, let me show an example:

```
[
       {
      "SourceId": "ABC123",
      "Target": {
          "Location": {
              "Subdirectory": "domainxxx/systemyyy/filezzz/file_XX%Y%m%d"
          }
      },
      "Source": {
          "Location": {
              "IncludePatterns": ["systemyyy/file_XX*"],
              "DatePattern": "file_%Y%m%d"
          }
      },
      "System": "systemyyy"
    }
]
```

That works successfully because normally the files to ingest comes with a date as part of the name of the file, but I got a file to ingest that has no date as part of the name of the file, instead it has a consecutive number, lets say "file_1084.dat","file_1085.dat",..,"file_1090.dat"..

So my question is if anyone have tried this before.. I tried with many other tags like //d{4} or [0-9]{4} or just *, but nothing seems to work..

Comment: a workaround (just for this case), as the digit in the file name is four digit, then using %Y works successfully, but that's not the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, as the digit in the file name is four digit, then using %Y works successfully.